# traversing vector which holds all nodes parent information to print all shortest paths between two nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I've tried to figure out how could I take all paths between two node.When I have all parents information.

I have a `vector<vector<int> >` which holds all parent ınformation.

Corresponding vector to picture below is:  : `< <2,3>,< >,<1>,<1> >`
Since 1 is the root, parent vector of 1 is empty.

```
-------       ---------
-  0  ------> -   2   -    //which means 2 is a parent of 0
-------       ---------
-------       ---------
-  0  ------> -   3   -   //which means 3 is also parent of 0
-------       ---------
-------       ---------
-  3  ------> -   1   -   //means 1 is parent of 3
-------       ---------
-------       ---------
-  2  ------> -   1   -   // means 1 is parent of 2
-------       ---------
```

I've got these information from a unweighted,undirected graph to find all shortest paths between 2 nodes.Lets say, I want to find the shortest paths between `node 1` and `node 0`

As you can see from the above, it has two different shortest paths, `1-3-0`  and `1-2-0`.

To be able to find both of them, I have to traverse my visit vector starting from 0 and goes to until 1 parent by parent or vice versa. Is there anyone to help me ,giving some clue,psodue code etc.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since its unweighted, a simple BFS should do the trick.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett I get these parent ınformation from BFS already.But just one shortest path is not enough to me, I need to find all of them betwen 2 nodes.So, I create a vector which holds parents for all node.Now I need to find all paths from starting node to end node

Comment: You know there may be an exponential number of shortest paths?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett yea I know it, but since I'm dealing with small numbers,it doesnt matter

Comment: ok, two strategies come to mind. Easiest involves knowing the distance in advance, but since you said you did a BFS already, do you know that?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett sorry but I couldnt understand what you said ?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett I have an idea but I think its overkill. Since I know parents information,like above, if I call this vector with dfs with two node source and destination, it gives me all paths and all of them will be shortest path since the input vector is the return of bfs ?

Comment: Meanwhile, I found this for you: http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=641

Comment: @RichardPlunkett thanks,I'm sure It'll  be really helpful.